# return not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, return, exit

I am having an issue with the `return` in my jquery code. I am expecting the `return` to exit the function once it's hit, but instead, the function continues to execute. I would expect I'm not the only person with this issue, but after a search I couldn't find the answer to my dilemma. Below is my function:

```
$(".myButtonClass").on("click", function() {
    $(".myTextBoxClass").children('input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).css('display') === "inline-block") {
            var doLeave = confirm("Does the user want to move forward");

            if (!doLeave) {
                return;
            }
        }
    });
    document.vendorEdit.action = "newPage.asp";
    document.vendorEdit.submit();
});
```

What am I doing incorrectly guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two functions, and you have to give 'return false' in the two functions
Try this:

```
  $(".myButtonClass").on("click", function() {
        var valid = true;
        $(".myTextBoxClass").children('input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).css('display') === "inline-block") {
                var doLeave = confirm("Does the user want to move forward");

                if (!doLeave) {
                    valid = false;      
                    return false;
                }            
            }


        });

        if(!valid){ 
          return false;
        };
        document.vendorEdit.action = "newPage.asp";
        document.vendorEdit.submit();
    });
```

Comment: This is it, I need the `false` after the `return`. I just realized that I had the two functions. This is what happens when you don't get sleep. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

You need `return false;` to exit a `.each` loop. `return true;` to go to the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You current `return` statement is causing the `each` loop to break instead of returning from the `event handler`. Set flag in condition `doLeave` block before exiting each loop using return statement and use that `flag` to return from event handler.

```
$(".myButtonClass").on("click", function() {
    var flagToReturn = false;
    $(".myTextBoxClass").children('input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).css('display') === "inline-block") {
            var doLeave = confirm("Does the user want to move forward");

            if (!doLeave) {
                flagToReturn = true;      
                return;
            }            
        }
        if(flagToReturn) return;

    });
    document.vendorEdit.action = "newPage.asp";
    document.vendorEdit.submit();
});
```

Comment: But both your returns are inside `each`

Comment: But the each loop doesn't stop executing on the `return`. It keeps going.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".myButtonClass").on("click", function() {
self= this ; 

    selft. flagToReturn = false;
    $(".myTextBoxClass").children('input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).css('display') === "inline-block") {
            var doLeave = confirm("Does the user want to move forward");

            if (!doLeave) {
                 selft. flagToReturn = true;      
                return;
            }            
        }
        if( selft. flagToReturn ) return;

    });
    document.vendorEdit.action = "newPage.asp";
    document.vendorEdit.submit();
});
```